# gif image is not working in Gallery in Nexus 5

Tags: nexus-5, gallery

i have downloaded some  gif images from `tumblr.com`. but is is not working in my Nexus 5 Gallery (Android 4.4.4).

It's fine in my Samsung Galaxy S4. So, how to display gif image in my Nexus 5?

Any one has any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not displaying a *.gif image is more-likely related to the application you are trying to view the image with, rather than being device specific.

Take a look on the Google PlayStore for an alternative picture/gallery application. I know of one called "GIF Player" which could be of use in the worst-case scenario.